# Selecting all rows with the same ID number, then iterating - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sorted list of ID's in Excel. I want to grab all the rows with the same ID, then I'll be manipulating them.

```
Sub Selectingabox()
Dim I As Integer
Dim N As Integer
'Defining
I = 1
N = 1
'Initializing
While I < 3000
'If I have more than 3k rows I'm in serious trouble anyways
If Range("A" & I).Select = Range("A" & I + 1).Select Then
 I = I + 1
Else: Range("A" & N, "AJ" & I).Select
'Lots of stuff manipulating the data range we just selected
N = I + 1
'The new top row
I = I + 1
'The new bottom row


Wend
End Sub
```

Not quite working.. the wend is unhappy with me, and I'm not sure why. Also have no idea if the code will work!

Comment: should there be an `end if` in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

- dim your values as long rather than integer, so you won't get an error at row 32k
- Use a FOR loop rather than a while loop to make your code more efficient
- Rather then using number 3000 you can use VBA to find the last row automatically using `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`
- I would not recommend using `.Select` in your code. What are you trying to manipulate?

  ```
  Sub Selectingabox()
  Dim I As Long
  Dim N As Long
  Dim lastrow As Long

  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  N = 1

  For I = 1 To lastrow
      If I = lastrow Then
          If Range("A" & I).Value <> Range("A" & I - 1).Value Then
          Range("A" & N & ":AJ" & I).Select
          N = I + 1
          End If
      Else
          If Range("A" & I).Value <> Range("A" & I + 1).Value Then
              Range("A" & N & ":AJ" & I).Select
          'Lots of stuff manipulating the data range we just selected
          N = I + 1
          End If
      End If
  Next I
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is run a solver on multiple data sets. The data sets are represented by their unique ID. I'm semi-new to VBA, so I tend to default to chunkier methods that I know work, since I don't know the more elegant solutions. In this case I need to paste the data into my solver sheet, the run the solver - I've got that part figured out, I'm just struggling with selecting the data. Thank you for your help, I'll try this!

Comment: Just realized that the code does not assess the last row. Just updated the code to include the assessment of the last row.

Comment: Hey Pete- I really appreciate all of your help. It seems like the (updated!) code is truncating the last line. I believe N = I is the correct method?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `End If` into your code - that will resolve the Compile Error

```
Sub Selectingabox()
Dim I As Integer
Dim N As Integer
'Defining
I = 1
N = 1
'Initializing
While I < 3000
'If I have more than 3k rows I'm in serious trouble anyways
If Range("A" & I).Select = Range("A" & I + 1).Select Then
 I = I + 1
Else: Range("A" & N, "AJ" & I).Select
'Lots of stuff manipulating the data range we just selected
N = I + 1
'The new top row
I = I + 1
'The new bottom row
End If ' add this here

Wend
End Sub
```